# How can I add a coloured square in front of several list items?

Tags: html, css

How can I style list items like this?

[image]

So some kind of colored square before the text. I was looking into this but couldn't find it :

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

They don't have to be list items but it seemed to me convinient because it is some kind of list which I would like to style and display in the same line not in different lines like in image above.

I've tried this :

```
<ul class="ordering">
<li><div></div><span>One</span></li>
<li><div></div><span>Two</span></li>
<li><div></div><span>Three</span></li>
</ul>
```

and with this css :

```
.ordering {
    list-style:none;
    min-width:250px;
}
.ordering div{
         width: 12px; height: 12px; float: left;
    }
.ordering span{
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 11px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
```

The problem I encounter is that I can't seperate them (they're glued together), and the other one when I have many items which don't fit in the size of `ordering` class they break line but the square remains in the previous line so square + text isn't being treated as one part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tried in the right way. Only additional thing is you can minimize the html structure and use `nth-child()` property

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ordering">
<li><span></span>One</li>
<li><span></span>Two</li>
<li><span></span>Three</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.ordering {    list-style:none;   min-width:250px; }
ul.ordering li{ 
  display:block; 
  clear:left; 
  vertical-align:middle;  
  font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 20px; 
  padding-left: 5px; }
ul.ordering li span{  width: 12px; height: 12px; background:red;  display:inline-block; margin-right:6px }
ul.ordering li:nth-child(2) span{ background:green !important;  }
ul.ordering li:nth-child(3) span{ background:blue !important;  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LY7J7/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to float anything:

```
.ordering div {
     width: 12px; height: 12px; display: inline-block;
}

.ordering span{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

(If you want it this to work in IE 7 and earlier, you'll need to change the `<div>` to a `<span>`, or some other inline element) e.g.:

```
.ordering span.colouredSquare {
     width: 12px; height: 12px; display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I encounter is that I can't seperate them (they're glued together), and the other one when I have many items which don't fit in the size of ordering class they break line but the square remains in the previous line so square + text isn't being treated as one part

All you need to do is give your `li` elements a display property of `display: inline-block`. That should fix your spacing issue and make the square & text move as a "block" i.e.

```
.ordering li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can clean up your markup a little by the power of pseudo elements.

**HTML** (note: only one child element to the list item)

```
<ul>
  <li><p>Bender</p></li>
  <li><p>Fry</p></li>
  <li><p>Leela</p></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { margin: 10px; }
li { position: relative; }

p:before {
  background: #bb3333;
  content: ".";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  width: 10px;
}

li:nth-child(2) p:before { background: #33bb33; }
li:nth-child(3) p:before { background: #3333bb; }
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uNR2M/2/

Instead of `nth-child` I think I would apply classes instead, as it is slightly better for performance.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
<li>
    <div></div><span>One</span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</li>
```

You should add some clearfix before the closing li.

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use the native list bullet points as these are not stylable.
You can use nested divs and spans but IMO it's cleaner to style `:before` pseudo-element, eg.:

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ezexeg/3/)

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li class="red">item</li>
    <li class="blue">item</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
li { 
    position: relative; 
    list-style: none; 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin-left: 30px;
    }
li:before {
    content: ' ';
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 5px;
    background: green;
}
.red:before { background: red; }
.blue:before { background: blue; }
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but remember that traditionally the only valid child of a `ul` is a `li`. Are pseudo elements an exception?

Comment: @Nix Your right, but if you have a look at the html structure - there are only <li> elements. :before is a pseudo-element which physically doesn't exist in html structure, but can be styled visually.